# FileOutputStream write files android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, save, overwrite

I have an []int array with 76800 cells. 
I need to save this data to a file while my app is running .  It will be great if it could be saved as a csv but txt file is also fine . So i have written a code that write this data to a txt file but it run extremely slow. 
this is the part of the code that write the file:

```
    try {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename2);


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
        for (int i = 1; i < Pixels.length ; i++) {

            fos.write(String.valueOf( (double)Math.round((Pixels[i] )*100)/100).getBytes());
            fos.write(",".getBytes());

        }
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While my app needs to override this file and it does so but extremely slow 7-10 seconds per array to file saving . 
anyone have a better writing method / solution ?

Comment: Try wrapping your `fos` with `BufferedOutputStream` to enable buffering.

Comment: `(double)Math.round((Pixels[i] )*100)/100`. ?? What should that do? Takes a lot of time. Does nothing. Please explain what you want.

Comment: (Pixels[i] ) is a number with several numbers after the decimal point for example : 200.234535298  then i multiply it by 100 and round it. then divide it by 100 and i get 200.23 . i thought that it should reduce the size of the file because i don't need such a precision.

Comment: #Roman , i have done what you suggested and indeed it helped but still not sufficient . any more ideas ? is there a way to avoid the loop ?